# How can bash screen be setup in the background and brought to the front later?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

This a deeper explanation for the question.

My goal is:

1. Start a bash shell configured with a set of environment variables, but running in the background.
2. Launch about five [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) commands in the bash shell, each executing its own commands, but using the environment variables set in the bash shell. The `screen` commands should all be arranged in the bash window, preferably tiled.
3. Call up the bash shell later, with the all the `screen` commands showing.
4. Close the bash shell and the associated `screen` when done.

Comment: @KingSkippus There are quite a few good bash and screen related answers here, so I will give it sometime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after some time on your question there is some observations:

line 2: *commands should all be arranged in the bash window, preferably tiled* is not possible, as when detached, *there is no windows*.

So when you re-attach, you will always see only one *pseudo-tty*.

But to do approximatively what asked for, try the following:

First create a RCfile as typing: `cat >screenRcTest` whith the following:

```
setenv MyVariable Test
screen -t Top top
screen -t VMStat vmstat -n 1
screen -t OpenPorts watch -n 2 'netstat -tan | grep LISTEN'
screen -t IF-Configs watch -n2 'ip -s link show | grep -v "^ *[RT]X: bytes"'
screen -t "Bourne Again Shell" /bin/bash -i
```

Than prepare a `run` wrapper as:

```
screen -ls | grep -q screenTest || screen -dmS screenTest -c ./screenRcTest
```

this will run a new screen session in background if not already exist.

For building *tiled* presentation, prepare another shell script as `cat >screenSplitTest`

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line ;do
    screen -X $line
done <<eof
split
split
resize 20
split -v
resize 82
select 0
focus
select 1
focus
split -v
select 2
focus
select 3
focus
select 4
eof
```

and don't forget `chmod +x screenSplitTest`.

Finally run the *display command* as:

```
xterm -fn 9x15 -geom 160x60 -exec screen -DrS screenTest
```

This will open a new window with only a `bash` ready.

In this *inner* bash, hit simply:

```
./screenSplitTest
```

This will split your window and let you ready again, in your bash session.

[image: result screenshoot]

Type now:

```
echo $MyVariable
Test
```

So you will see how Environment variable as passed to child bash.

**Edit addition:**

After doing all, you could hit the following in your *inner* bash:

```
trap '[ $(tput lines) == 60 ] && [ $(tput cols) == 160 ] && ./screenSplitTest' WINCH
```

So you could disconnect by typing: `Ctrl-A d` than next time you run `xterm` whith same arguments and geometry, the script screenSplitTest will be initiated automatically.

**Edit 2**

And now, you could even install this `trap` in your `.bashrc`, using `MyVariable` for ensuring that bash is a child of *screenRcTest* screen (after moving `screenSplitTest` to a hidden file in `$HOME/.screenSplitTest` for constance):

```
[ "$TERM.$MyVariable" == "screen.Test" ] && \
    trap '[ $(tput lines) == 60 ] && [ $(tput cols) == 160 ] && $HOME/.screenSplitTest' WINCH
```

Comment: @FHauri All I can say is is Wow! I see you just joined superuser. Where were you in the past when we needed you? :)

Comment: Thank! I've added a little `.bashrc` line to make them more *automatic*.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you cannot tile screen instances, but you can tile tmux instances. What you could do is to create an rc-file for the shared environment settings, and then load this to each of your 5 bash shells using `bash --rcfile <your file here>`.

The bash shells would be started by launching tmux, and when inside, execute some command to create a new split (for instance Ctrl+b % for a vertical split, using standard settings) for each bash instance.

Comment: tmux was another utility I had in mind but I have no experience with it but I know it will be useful one day.